# C# - Thread Abort Exception (Thread Abort Exception) rethrowing itself

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception

I have the current code:

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        while (true)
        {

            try
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
            }
            catch (ThreadAbortException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Abort!");
                Thread.ResetAbort();
            }


            Console.WriteLine("now waiting");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I know the method `ResetAbort` is supposed to prevent the `ThreadAbortException` from continue to re-throw itself even when a `catch` statement is catching it, but my question is this:

If anyone can use the `ResetAbort` method, then what's the point of the exception specially re-throw itself?

the user can just do

```
    catch (ThreadAbortException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Abort!");
        throw ex;
    }
```

Comment: Don't "throw ex".  Just "throw".  The former will reset the stack trace.

Comment: The basic flaw in your reasoning is that you expect programmers to always write a catch clause for TAE.  Of course they don't.  Not in the least because they don't expect to be treated that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point of `ThreadAbortException` rethrowing itself is to make sure the thread terminates unless the user explicitly calls `ResetAbort`.

Let me explain:

```
try
{
    // ... Thread abort happens somewhere in here
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _log.Error(ex);
}
```

Here you have a typical example of code that ensures no exception propagates from inside the `try` block. I know that catching `Exception` is bad practice, but code like this exists nonetheless.

If you call `Abort` while the thread is inside the `try` block you still want it to abort. You just can't rely on users writing this sort of code everywhere:

```
try
{
    // ... Thread abort happens somewhere in here
}
catch (ThreadAbortException)
{
    throw; // No, you'll NEVER see code like this in real life
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _log.Error(ex);
}
```

So, in order to provide a *sort of* reliable `Abort`, the exception has to be automatically rethrown, or it may easily get discarded by accident.

`ResetAbort` is meant for the very rare case when you specifically detect a thread abort, and you exactly know why it happenned, and you want to prevent it.

Needless to say, the use cases for this are extremely rare. Thread aborts are treated by the runtime in a very special way, and you should avoid them whenever possible. Heck, they even aren't reliable as you pointed out, and all this discussion is ignoring [CER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228973.aspx)s which make matters worse.

Answer (score 7):

`Thread.ResetAbort()` is not meant for common use.  It can cause undesired behavior if you don't understand why the thead abort happened.  Because of this, and probably to make ASP.NETs stable in shared hosting environments, the `SecurityPermissionFlag.ControlThread` permission is required to call `Thread.ResetAbort()`

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.resetabort%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Also, if the thread takes too long to abort, a rude thread abort can occur, which pays no attention to `ResetAbort`.

Comment: Also, if you do too many aborts (as you are doing in a kind of infinite loop), the IIS environment will think you are a bad program and shut you down. That could be the cause for the "spurious" thread abort you are seeing.

Answer (score 2):

The point is to define a default behavior in which the exception is rethrown, seeing as how there is a remote chance that the user will have any point of continuing the thread.

Moreover, `ResetAbort` has a security demand and can not be called by any code.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but your original answer was substantially different.

Comment: @DavidCrowell The second line was missing.

Answer (score 2):

Because Aborting a thread doesn't necessarily mean an exception will be thrown. For the *Abort Procedure* the `catch (ThreadAbortException)` block is just another critical region of code. It only gives us a thread safe and convenient way of detecting if the current thread is being aborted (and maybe with some state being passed too) in case we want to do something special. Other than that, it is like any other critical region (like a finally block) where it will terminate the thread after its execution.

At the same time, in your example `Abort` is called *synchronously* (which is actually safe to do) and in that case *it is* very similar to throwing an exception. Things only get interesting and dangerous when it's called *asynchronously* from another thread, due to the Abort procedure being more complicated than just throwing an exception: In essence, first, thread is marked as being aborted, then critical code regions (for example finally blocks) are executed and only then the exception is thrown, if the *AbortRequested* flag is still set on the thread, and so on.

Code below illustrates this fact by recovering an aborted thread without catching any exceptions:

```
var inFinally = new ManualResetEvent(false);
var abortCalled = new ManualResetEvent(false);

var t = new Thread(_ =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Thread started..");
    try
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        inFinally.Set();
        abortCalled.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine(" ThreadState (before): " + Thread.CurrentThread.ThreadState);

        // This isn't thread safe, and ugly?
        if ((Thread.CurrentThread.ThreadState & ThreadState.AbortRequested) != 0)
        {
            Thread.ResetAbort();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(" ThreadState (after): " + Thread.CurrentThread.ThreadState);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Executed because we called Thread.ResetAbort()");
});

t.Start();

inFinally.WaitOne();

// Call from another thread because Abort()
// blocks while in finally block
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => t.Abort());

while ((t.ThreadState & ThreadState.AbortRequested) == 0)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1);
}

abortCalled.Set();

Console.ReadLine();

//  Output:
//--------------------------------------------------
// Thread started..
//  ThreadState (before): AbortRequested
//  ThreadState (after): Running
// Executed because we called Thread.ResetAbort()
```

Now, I must be honest: I am not entirely sure how one could use this feature and create something useful. But it sounds like Thread.Abort API was (probably still is, I don't know) used to facilitate thread and AppDomain reuse in frameworks like ASP.NET.

In one of Joe Duffy's Blog entries, [Managed code and asynchronous exception hardening](http://joeduffyblog.com/2009/03/13/managed-code-and-asynchronous-exception-hardening/), he talks about ResetAbort and the Abort API:

> Some framework infrastructure, most notably ASP.NET, even aborts individual threads
>   routinely without unloading the domain.  They backstop the ThreadAbortExceptions, call
>   ResetAbort on the thread and reuse it or return it to the CLR ThreadPool.

I can imagine it can be used in a framework to reuse the managed threads, reducing the overhead. However, the problems (bad thread synchronization design, bad exception handling, dead locks and so on) introduced in user code, by this easily misunderstood API, rendered the Abort and ResetAbort calls more troublesome than useful.